# Character won't push to top of stack?

Tags: java

So for this project, we have our own pre-programmed class for creating stacks, and we need to use this class to create and use stacks instead of the Stacks class that already comes with Java. The problem I'm having is that when I push the character to the top of the stack it still remains empty, do you see why this might be happening?

Here is the code in our stacks class for pushing

StackOfCharacters.java (push method):

```
/**
 * Puts the character value at the top of the stack.
 * @param value adds specified character to the stack
 */
public void push ( Character value )
{
    //if the stack is full, allocate a larger array
    if (  full() )
        makeLarger();
    //add the new value to the top of the stack
    if (value != null) {
        list[size] = value;
        size++;
    }
}
```

but when I call it it comes up as empty

balance.java

```
public void isBalanced(String x){

    char d = x.charAt(1);
    System.out.println(d);

    new StackOfCharacters();
    new StackOfCharacters().push(x.charAt(1));
    System.out.println(new StackOfCharacters().peek());
    System.out.println(new StackOfCharacters().empty());

}
```

main class:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type a string to Balance Check: ");
    String s = input.nextLine();  // input String
    System.out.println();

    new BalanceChecks().isBalanced(s);
```

the StackOfCharacters.java file is supposedly 100% correct in its coding i'm just confused about why everything is working except pushing??

Thank you!

Comment: i didn't use char d here because i was checking to see if it might work if i pushed using x.charAt(1) directly as the parameter btw, and forgot to switch it back to d

Comment: what type of array is `list`? You're attempting to push a `Character` object into what I might assume is a `char` array?

Comment: Each time you call `isBalanced` you're creating a new instance of `StackOfCharacters` for each instruction.

Comment: yes it's a char array

Comment: Ohhhhhh hm if i don't put "new" in front of it eclipse tells me it can't access it and if i don't put StackOfCharacters().whatever in front of the method it tells me to create a new method for it. Is this just a problem with syntax of calling methods in other classes? How is it properly done?

Comment: @maribov Create the object once and store the reference in a variable and then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep using the same `StackOfCharacters` instance:

```
public void isBalanced(String x){

    char d = x.charAt(1);
    System.out.println(d);

    StackOfCharacters s = new StackOfCharacters();
    s.push(d);
    System.out.println(s.peek());
    System.out.println(s.empty());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new objects all the time, instead of using the same one. Create an instance of your class and push the characters to this instance :-)

```
StackOfCharacters soc = new StackOfCharacters();
soc.push(1);
System.out.println(soc.peek());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new StackOfCharacters instead of pushing/peeking to the same one.

```
public void isBalanced(String x){

    char d = x.charAt(1);
    System.out.println(d);

    StackOfCharacters thisStack = new StackOfCharacters();
    thisStack.push(x.charAt(1));
    System.out.println(thisStack.peek());
    System.out.println(thisStack.empty());

}
```